# How do I put text and image side by side with the image positioned central to the block of tex

Tags: graphics, wrapfigure

How do I put text and image side by side like the attached image where the image is positioned central to the block of text please?

I tried the `wrapfigure` package, but it doesn't give the intended result. This is my code:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.15\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=0.9\linewidth]{figures/engineer}
\caption*{Ben}
\end{wrapfigure}

\textbf{Ben} is a technician working for the Ministry of Defense. He was asked to prepare 300 multi-purpose tents (MPT II) for a mission in Mali. Ben is a prudent person. The climate in Mali is extremely hot. Ben does not want to provide an oversized system because he does not want to give the soldiers the opportunity to set too low temperature in the tents in order to prevent health problems caused by the temperature shock. Moreover, oversized systems make noise and consume more fuel. Larger fuel consumption causes additional costs and the need to refill the fuel tank more often, which is not convenient. Ben wants to size the HVAC system properly so that there are no complaints and the soldiers’ health is protected. Also, he wants to convince the soldiers to install shading so that the cooling demand and fuel consumption is decreased.
```

This is the intended display:

[image: Intended Display]

This is how it currently looks:

[image: actual]

Comment: Hi, I have edited the OP with my code and current result

Answer (score 2):

I hope using `minipage` environment will satisfy you, here what I've got :

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[C]{0.25\linewidth}
\begin{flushleft}
\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{Ben.png}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[C]{0.75\linewidth}
\textbf{Ben} is a technician working for the Ministry of Defense. He was asked to prepare 300 multi-purpose tents (MPT II) for a mission in Mali. Ben is a prudent person. The climate in Mali is extremely hot. Ben does not want to provide an oversized system because he does not want to give the soldiers the opportunity to set too low temperature in the tents in order to prevent health problems caused by the temperature shock. Moreover, oversized systems make noise and consume more fuel. Larger fuel consumption causes additional costs and the need to refill the fuel tank more often, which is not convenient. Ben wants to size the HVAC system properly so that there are no complaints and the soldiers’ health is protected. Also, he wants to convince the soldiers to install shading so that the cooling demand and fuel consumption is decreased. 
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Have a nice day :D !

Comment: Thanks euler_med

Answer (score 1):

wrapfig takes an optional argument that specifies how many lines tall the figure should occupy.  You also need a `\noindent`:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}[14]{l}{0.15\textwidth} % <----- added [14]
\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Ben}
\end{wrapfigure}
\noindent % <----- added
\textbf{Ben} is a technician working for the Ministry of Defense. He was asked to prepare 300 multi-purpose tents (MPT II) for a mission in Mali. Ben is a prudent person. The climate in Mali is extremely hot. Ben does not want to provide an oversized system because he does not want to give the soldiers the opportunity to set too low temperature in the tents in order to prevent health problems caused by the temperature shock. Moreover, oversized systems make noise and consume more fuel. Larger fuel consumption causes additional costs and the need to refill the fuel tank more often, which is not convenient. Ben wants to size the HVAC system properly so that there are no complaints and the soldiers’ health is protected. Also, he wants to convince the soldiers to install shading so that the cooling demand and fuel consumption is decreased.
\end{document}
```

[image: code output]

Comment: You still need to center the image inside a 14\baselineskip space:  `\parbox[c][14\baselineskip][c]{\linewidth}{...}`

Comment: An additional comment, the value '14' needs to changed, based on your no of lines of text

Comment: Thinking about it some more, wrapfig would be more appropriate if you intend for the text to wrap around the figure.  If you want the entirety of the text to have the same left hand side, you'd probably be better served with the tabular or minipage approach of the other answers.  That would let you not worry about the 14, and vertically centering the image.

Answer (score 1):

What about this answer - using the `floatrow` and `paracol` packages?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{floatrow}

\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}

\columnratio{0.15,0,85}
\begin{paracol}{2}

    \vspace*{\fill}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
    {\caption*{Ben}}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{figures/engineer.png}}
    \vspace*{\fill}

\switchcolumn
    \textbf{Ben} is a technician working for the Ministry of Defense. He was asked to prepare 300 multi-purpose tents (MPT II) for a mission in Mali. Ben is a prudent person. The climate in Mali is extremely hot. Ben does not want to provide an oversized system because he does not want to give the soldiers the opportunity to set too low temperature in the tents in order to prevent health problems caused by the temperature shock. Moreover, oversized systems make noise and consume more fuel. Larger fuel consumption causes additional costs and the need to refill the fuel tank more often, which is not convenient. Ben wants to size the HVAC system properly so that there are no complaints and the soldiers’ health is protected. Also, he wants to convince the soldiers to install shading so that the cooling demand and fuel consumption is decreased.
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image: centered fig to text]

Comment: Forgot to place `\noindent`  before Ben ..

Answer (score 0):

One of possibilities is use table where in the first column you insert image and in the second text.

For table I suggest to use `zblr` of `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\sffamily
\noindent%
\begin{tblr}{colspec={@{} X[c,m] X[4,j,m] @{}}}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}
\par\medskip\footnotesize
Lady Queen Duck
    &   \lipsum[11]
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Equal result can be obtained by use of `tabularx` table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\sffamily
\noindent%
\begingroup
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} m{0.2\linewidth} X @{}}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}
\par\medskip\footnotesize
Lady Queen Duck
    &   \lipsum[11]
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Rresult is equal as before.